# Feign throws 404 Not Found but the link does work

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign

I have some questions about using Feign in Spring Cloud. I have a FeignClient:

```java
@FeignClient(name = "device-code", url = AzureTokenClient.BASE_URL)
public interface AzureTokenClient {
    String SCOPE = URLEncoder.encode("offline_access files.read.all", Charsets.UTF_8);
    String BASE_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";

    @PostMapping(value = "/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    Map<String, Object> getDeviceCode(@RequestBody Request dto);
}

record Request(
    @RequestParam(name = "client_id") String clientId,
    @RequestParam(name = "scope") String scope
) implements Serializable { }
```

But when I call function `DeviceCodeCheckClient#getTokenByDeviceCode`, it throw `feign.FeignException$NotFound`:

```
10:29:28.267 ERROR (DirectJDKLog.java:175): Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404 Not Found] during [POST] to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode] [AzureTokenClient#getDeviceCode(Request)]: []] with root cause
feign.FeignException$NotFound: [404 Not Found] during [POST] to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode] [AzureTokenClient#getDeviceCode(Request)]: []
    at feign.FeignException.clientErrorStatus(FeignException.java:219)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:185)
...
```

Obviously, the link `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode` is correct and accessible. I would like to know why Feign is giving error 404 and how can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation `@RequestBody` will serialize the object to `json` or `xml`, but `consumes` specifies the format as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which causes the body in the request sent by Feign to be empty, so the microsoft server returns a `404 Not Found` response.

To solve this problem, the `@RequestBody` annotation should be removed:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/common/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Map<String, Object> getDeviceCode(Request dto);
```